# unable to use .env variables in express js

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I am new to node and express js facing issue to access .env variables
webapp.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

app.listen(process.env.app_port, () => { 
//console.log("server running....", process.env);
console.log("server running....", process.env.app_port);
});
```

.env file:

```
node_env : development
app_port : 5000
db_port : 3306
host : localhost
user : root
password : 
database : job_portal
connectionLimit : 10
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webservices",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webapp.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon webapp.js",
    "dev": "nodemon webapp.js"    
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

I am trying to access variable in webapp.js from .env file but it return undefined how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure your .env file is in the root and value assignment is =  not  :  , like node_env=development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your.env file to

```
node_env = development
app_port = 5000
db_port = 3306
host = localhost
user = root
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   #YOU VARIABLES SHOULD CAPITALISE AS THIS IS THE CONVENTION
    NODE_ENV=development
    APP_PORT=5000
    DB_PORT=3306
    HOST=localhost
    USER=root
```